# How to limit length of data in a cell of excel reports

Tags: python, odoo

I am creating a report in excel format.I am fetching data from fields of database and writing it in cell of excel sheet.But for one field the data is too long,such that it spreads in many columns.What can I do to ,so that the data remains within that cell and is displayed more when we stretch the column.I tried increasing the width and height of the cell,but it didn't help.[image: screen shot of report]

Answer (score 0):

I think that most spreadsheet programs will let long text flow out of cells into neighbouring cells if those neighbours are blank. Try putting an X in the next cell to see if it stops the text from flowing. If that works, then experiment with a space or a non-breaking space character.

Answer (score 0):

Format the cell with the programmatic equivalent of:

select the cell
click on Format Cells
click on Alignment
tick Wrap